# Let $M$ be a matrix of dimension $n \times n$ with coefficientes in $\mathbb{R}$. How do I prove that $\mathbb{R}^n =$ Kernel (M) $\oplus$ Range(M)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $M$ be a matrix of dimension $n \times n$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$. Let $T: \mathbb{R}  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ the linear map given by $T(v) = Mv$. How can I prove that $\mathbb{R}^n =$ Kernel (T) $\oplus$ Range(T)?

In fact, I've seen that this is true for any simmetric operator sending any finite-dimensional vector space into itself. How can I prove it?

Comment: You can't prove it because it's false. Can you contruct a $2\times 2$ matrix whose null space and image are both the $x$ axis?

Comment: You might try proving instead $\Bbb R^n = \ker T\oplus \text{range}(T^*)$. Indeed, these are orthogonal subspaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\range}{range}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\span}{span}$

As stated in comments: your question, as stated, is incorrect. Indeed, consider $$M = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$
Then, $\range(T) = \span\{\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\end{bmatrix}^\top\} = \ker(T).$

---

However, as you mention later, the statement is indeed true if $M$ is symmetric. We prove a more general result (as mentioned in the comments.)
Let $T^*$ denote the operator denoting multiplication by $M^\top$.

**Claim.** $\range(T^*) \cap \ker(T) = \{0\}$.
*Proof.* Suppose $v \in \range(T^*) \cap \ker(T).$ Then, $T(v) = 0$ and $v = T^*(w)$ for some $w \in \Bbb R^n$.
This means that $T(T^*(w)) = 0.$ Thus, $\langle w, T(T^*(w)) \rangle = 0$ or $\langle T^*(w), T^*(w) \rangle = 0$. This implies that $T^*(w) = 0$ or $v = 0,$ as desired. $\Box$

(In terms of matrices, we had $MM^\top w = 0$ which gave us $w^\top M M^\top w = 0$ or $(M^\top w)^\top (M^\top w) = 0$ which gives us that $\|M^\top w\|^2 = 0$ or $M^\top w = 0$.)

Now, by the rank-nullity theorem, we know that $n = \dim\range(T) + \dim\ker(T).$ We also have $\dim \range(T) = \dim \range(T^*)$. Accompanied with the claim, we see that $\range(T^*) \oplus \ker(T) = \Bbb R^n$ since the dimensions match.

---

In particular, if $M$ is symmetric, we have $T^* = T$ in the above and the result follows. The above result is also true for a general operator $T : V \to V$, where $V$ is a finite dimensional inner product space. You need to know what $T^*$ means in the general case. Again, for the case that $T$ is symmetric, i.e., $T = T^*$, the result follows.